# Difficulties merging accounts

Tags: support

hopefully this is an MO.meta appropriate topic.

I have tried merging two accounts (I created the alternate account one day when I forgot my password and wanted to ask a quick question on mobile) and have gone through the suggested process (have them email both accounts' emails and verify), but it has failed every time (I think I've tried three times).

Is there anything else I can do to get these accounts merged?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "it has failed every time"? E.g., has SE explicitly denied your request to merge these accounts?

Comment: @arjafi No. Sorry! They have done the standard procedure of sending me two copies of the email, I have followed the instructions (sequentially clicking a link acknowledging ownership of the respective accounts) but have yet to actually have the accounts merged. Is that clear enough?

Comment: So it hasn't failed, it just hasn't been completed. I'm pretty certain that the actual merging of accounts is not an automated process, but is done manually. SE staff can be very busy, and it may take time to process requests. (Also, requests sent during the weekends are very unlikely to get a rapid response.) If it's been less than one week since the first submission I would suggest that there's nothing to be concerned with. After this I would recommend against submitting multiple merge requests, but instead a custom "other" contact, or email `team@stackexchange.com` directly.

Comment: @arjafi Ah, excellent! Thank you! I didn't realize that it wasn't an automated process. :) I will just wait for a week or so then.